# .length no funciona en un objeto recibido por JSON

Tags: jquery

Tengo este codigo jquery:

```
$("#bus_productos").keypress(function(e) {
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code==13){    
const q = $(this).val();
$.ajax({url: "cpu.php",type: 'POST',data: 'proc=getProductosSearch&q='+q,dataType:'JSON',
success:function(data){    
console.log(data);
    if(data.error==null){
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
$('#product_busqueda').append(`
<tr id-producto="`+data[i].id_lote+`">
  <td>
    <div class="flex-ali-cen label-10">
    <div class="producto_nombre">`+data[i].producto+`</div>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td class="bold t-center">`+data[i].producto+`</td>
  <td class="t-center">`+data[i].precio+`</td>
  <td>
    <div  class="flex label-5">
    <button class="ui-2 icono-min" style="display:none;"><img src="<?php img("foto.svg");?>" style="width:22px;"></button>
    <button class="btn-ico noinvert btn-add" add-item="`+data[i].id_lote+`"><img src="<?php img("add_color.svg");?>" style="width:28px"></button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
`);

}

}else{
  alert("El producto no fue encontrado");
}

}});
}
});
```

y esto me devuelve mi php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a la hora que quiero recorrer el objeto JSON recibido me sale que data.length es `undefined`
No muestro mi codigo php porque es complicado pero basicamente busca en la base de datos y todos los resultados los almacena en un array para luego mediante `json_encode()` lo codifique a json

Comment: Eso es un objeto. Los objetos **no tienen** `length`.

Comment: y como podria recorrerlo amigo ?

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer objetos en ese formato, existe la instrucción [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Para usarla, solo debes usarla de la siguiente manera

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

Hay otras opciones, como usar [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). pero la más sencilla me parece que es for...in